# Send different values of eth to multiple different addresses

Tags: solidity, web3.py

I want to send different values of ethers to multiple different addresses in one single transaction and for that I've created a smart contract, but I'm not getting how would I'll call the contract function by web3 py
Here's my contract code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract PayMultiple {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    function pay(address[] payees, uint[] values) public payable{
         //Make sure both arrays have matching lengths
         require(payees.length == values.length);

         //Make sure total of the values is the amount sent
        uint total = 0;
        for(uint i = 0; i < payees.length; i++){
            total = total.add(values[i]);
        }
        require(total == msg.value);

        //Actually send to the payees
        for(i = 0; i < payees.length; i++){
            payees[i].transfer(values[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your script abit.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract PayMultiple {

function pay(address[] memory payees, uint[] memory values) public payable{
     require(payees.length == values.length);

    uint total = 0;
    for(uint i = 0; i < payees.length; i++){
        total += values[i];
    }
    require(total == msg.value);

    for(uint i = 0; i < payees.length; i++){
        (bool success,) = payable(payees[i]).call{value:values[i]}("");
        require(success,"Not successfull");
    }
}
```

}

Try sending some WEI, for example:

Random addresses: `["0xdD870fA1b7C4700F2BD7f44238821C26f7392148","0x583031D1113aD414F02576BD6afaBfb302140225","0x4B0897b0513fdC7C541B6d9D7E929C4e5364D2dB"]`

Random values:

```
[3,3,4]
```

Make sure that you send 10 WEI.
If you send ETHER, than random values should be:

```
[300000000000000000,300000000000000000,400000000000000000]
```

Comment: Thank you for correction but I want the web3 py script by which I can interact with this contract